# Parenthesis/Insertion after "or"

Tags: grammar, parentheses, construction

Is it valid in English to use a construction like:

> Fog consists of tiny water droplets or, rarely, ice crystals.

If not, how can I elegantly solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's ok how you said it, but you can make it a little easier to read by stating something like this instead:

> Fog consists of tiny water droplets and occasionally ice crystals.

or

> Fog consists of tiny water droplets with the rare formation of ice crystals.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! +1 for the "occasioanlly". But do you think it is clear to the reader from your formulation, that ice crystals are only rarlely appearing? Couldn't I use "and, occasionally, ice crystals"?

Comment: Maybe my edit is better @matheburg